# vlookup functionality in Tableau

Tags: tableau-desktop

I have a dataset where client wants to analyse the items existing in a particular month against the data selected in any previous months. Ex: The items and Lnumber in May 2022 is compared against items & Lnumber in May 2023. If all the items are sold out in May 2022, the new data (i.e may 2023) will not have any information so those items&Lno are marked as cleared, the rest will go according to age band mentioned in screenshot.[image: May2022],[image: May2023],[image: final]I have attached sample data format. Any help/ideas on how to approach would be really helpful